# Binding a Sencha Touch Model to a fieldset

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a way to bind a model to a fieldset so that code like this can be avoided (manually setting each field of a model).

```
var vals = this.getUserDetail().getValues(),
            rec = this.getUserDetail().getRecord(),
            errorObject; // Ext.data.Errors
        rec.set('first', vals.first);
        rec.set('last', vals.last);
        rec.set('email', vals.email);
        errorObject = rec.validate();
```

Comment: not sure about touch api but extjs api has form.loadRecord(record) method

Comment: is a fieldset the same thing as a form?

Comment: fieldset in extjs is a layout container to arrange the fields properly, form is a very different beast

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the record to the form, not the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

yes in the same way as the form has a `.getValues()` method.

You can use `setValues({obj...})` to update the form values.  If your are using a "model/record" you might have to use `form.setValues(Model.data)`.

[link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setValues)